# Sending long messages on CAN FD using python-can library on vector hardware

Tags: python, can-bus

I am trying to send a message on CAN FD which is very long (DLC=70) but have been unsuccessful. I have been successful sending shorter messages (DLC=8)

I have set up the bus as follows using the python-can package :

```
can.interface.Bus(bustype='vector', app_name='CANoe', channel=[0], bitrate=500000, data_bitrate=2000000, fd=True)
```

Everything works as long as the messages are short.

The log files from CANoe shows that nothing is being written beyond the first 8 bits. I would really appreciate any help on this matter. Do let me know if the question is clearer with more detail

These are the messages I am trying to send

```py
    msg6 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=64,   data=messagedata1,  
    extended_id=False)
    task6 = bus.send(msg6)
    time.sleep(5)
    msg7 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=9,  data=trailingbits,  
    extended_id=False)
    task7 = bus.send(msg7)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: DLC=70 is too long even for CAN-FD. You would need to have a transport protocol such as ISO-TP on top. What happens, when you try with the maximum DLC=64?

Comment: even for DLC=64 the data gets copied only for the first 8...what do you think may be the problem here?

Comment: can you show more of your code. especially the part where you construct the message and send the message?

Comment: Ok, just for a background, the message is being constructed of bits that I am obtaining from an excel file. The same code works when the message length is within DLC=8   
`msg6 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=15,   data=messagedata1,  extended_id=False)`

`task6 = bus.send(msg6)`

`time.sleep(5)`
`msg7 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=9,  data=trailingbits,  extended_id=False)`

`task7 = bus.send(msg7)`

`time.sleep(5)`

Comment: Ok, I think I know what's the problem. I will create an answer. By the way, please include the last comment in the question, as it is essential information for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have indicated in your setup of the can-bus that it is CAN-FD, but you also need to include it in the messages that you construct, by setting `is_fd=True`.

So instead of

```
msg6 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=15, data=messagedata1, extended_id=False)
task6 = bus.send(msg6)

time.sleep(5)

msg7 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=9, data=trailingbits, extended_id=False)
task7 = bus.send(msg7)

time.sleep(5)
```

could you please try

```
msg6 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=15, data=messagedata1, is_fd=True, extended_id=False)
task6 = bus.send(msg6)

time.sleep(5)

msg7 = can.Message(arbitration_id=0x74A, dlc=9, data=trailingbits, is_fd=True, extended_id=False)
task7 = bus.send(msg7)

time.sleep(5)
```

For your reference please have a look at section 3.3. of the [python-can documentation](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/python-can/3.0.0/python-can.pdf).

Comment: sure..I will update the situation in a few hours :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but it turns out setting the fd flag in the bus configuration too let me start sending CAN FD messages. Add "fd=True" to the bus like this

busA=can.interface.Bus(bustype='socketcan',channel='vcan0',bitrate=500000, fd=True)